# Javascript - Order array of objects by two date properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array that contains two different kinds of objects, each with their own date field in which the key is different. See below:

```
const array = [
  { id: 1, occurs_at: '2017-02-03T07:00:01.000Z' },
  { id: 2, occurs_at: '2017-02-03T10:00:01.000Z' },
  { id: 3, start: '2017-02-03T04:00:01.000Z' },
  { id: 4, start: '2017-02-03T06:00:01.000Z' },
];
```

I'm trying to get them in ascending order, but I can't seem to find the solution. I've been using Lodash for other sorting based on a single property. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a way to know which key it'll be? Are there more than two different date keys? Or are 'occurs_at' and 'start' the only two possible date keys? Do the objects have more keys apart from the date and the id?

Comment: start and occurs_at are the only possible keys for the date?

Comment: @baao correct. Those would be the only possible keys.

Comment: Edit additional details into your question. Comments are for us to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Then Nina has answered your question... :-)

Comment: Just use plain `.sort()` with a comparator function that finds the date in each object and performs the comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could test for the wanted property and use only ones with a truthy value.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, occurs_at: '2017-02-03T07:00:01.000Z' }, { id: 2, occurs_at: '2017-02-03T10:00:01.000Z' }, { id: 3, start: '2017-02-03T04:00:01.000Z' }, { id: 4, start: '2017-02-03T06:00:01.000Z' }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.occurs_at || a.start).localeCompare(b.occurs_at || b.start);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) and [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick):

```
const sorted = _.sortBy(array, i => new Date(
  _(i)
    .pick(['occurs_at', 'start'])
    .values()
    .first()
));
```

If you know that the each collection item is going to have either an `occurs_at` or a `start` property that's a date string, you can use `pick()` to get both. Obviously only one exists, so this will return an object with the correct value.

At this point, you no longer care about the key, since you know that its an object with a single date value. So you get it using [values()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values) and [first()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#head).

Answer (score -3):

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(b.occurs_at) - new Date(a.occurs_at);
});
```